# how to do symmetric matrix's calculation with load balance?

Tags: multithreading, algorithm

I want calculate a `n x n` matrix `A`. It is symmetric, that is `A(i,j)` = `A(j,i)`

Suppose calculate the `A(i,j)` takes a long time, it will takes 1000s.

Suppose obtain `A(j,i)` from `A(i,j)` is just data copy, it is very fast, it will takes 0.00001s.

Each element of `A(i,j)` have no dependency, you can calculate anyone first if you like.

In order to obtain all element in matrix A fast, the symmertic attribute must be used.

I want using `n` worker to calculate matrix `A`. Worker `i` calculate row `i` of A.

A naive solution is

```
worker 1 calculate A(1,1), A(1,2), A(1,3), ...,  A(1,n)
worker 2 calculate         A(2,2), A(2,3), ...,  A(2,n)
worker 2 calculate                 A(3,3), ...,  A(3,n)
...
worker n calculate                               A(n,n)
then lower triangle part can obtain by upper triangle part.
```

This solution leads to `worker 1` needs calculate `n` element, but `worker n` only calculate `1` element. It is a load-unbalance solution.

I am looking for a load balance solution. Could any one give some advices? Thanks for your time.

Comment: You can use n/2 workers, each worker calculating rows i and n-i+1. Each worker would have n+1 operations instead of n.

Comment: @Burak Serdar you are right sir, Actually in my case, the system is distribute, I already have n worker. Each worker can calulate its row without communication with each other. So I want the n worker's solution.

Comment: That's a bit more involved. You have n^2/2 entries with n processors, so each processor gets n/2. The first gets the first half of row1, second gets the second half, third gets the first n entries of row2, fourth gets rest of row2 and an element of row3, etc.